# What happens if I hit a scalability target in Windows Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx) says there's a limit of 5 thousand Blob Storage requests per storage account per second.

> Transactions – Up to 5,000 entities/messages/blobs per second

What exactly happens if I hit this limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request fails with an error: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx (search 'Throttling' in the page).

> Throttling – These are requests that are being throttled due to the
>   transaction rate going over the per partition target throughput
>   described in the post “Windows Azure Storage Abstractions and their
>   Scalability Targets”. These throttled requests are counted as billable
>   transactions. When this occurs, the client is expected to use
>   exponential backoff and retry the request, which is provided by
>   default with the storage client library. If it is a reoccurring event
>   for the service, then the service should consider additional
>   partitioning of its data structures as described in the upcoming posts
>   on Blobs, Tables and Queues.

The error codes you might get back from the REST API are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179382.aspx - I can't immediately see which one would apply in a throttling context.